# How to use a library created using Bazel

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, bazel

I'm relatively new to Cpp and I was trying to build a simple app for a quant project. I've managed to use Bazel to convert a chunk of my code to a library residing in the `bazel-bin` directory in my repository as a `.lib` file.

However, I'm not able to figure out how to use this library in my `main.cpp` which is outside the library I created. Could anyone help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I think, there is a `.lib` file that you want to use it (technically speaking, you need to *link* that `.lib` file to another app, or accessing in the `main.cpp`).
Ok, it depends on what build-system you use.

for **MSVC**:
Add the full path of the `.lib` file to `Project Property Page -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`.
and don't forget to add the path to `.h` files (include path) to `Project Property Page -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`

It's the same for other build systems, you have to link it to the final built item.

for **gcc** there is a `-L` flag for the `lib` and a `-h` flag to point to the include directories.

in **CMake**:

```
include_directories(
    path/to/include/directory
)
link_directories(
    path/to/directory/that/lib/lives
)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main lib_file_name)
```

if the lib file name is `lib_file_name.lib` you should not include `.lib` (just for cmake)